# SQL filtering multiple joins by row-specific date window

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to obtain aggregate stats of each customer in their first 60 days. Each user has a different join date, which resides in a `user_info` table. Currently, the best way I have of doing this is to repeatedly join to the user table each time I need to get aggregate stats from another table, then joining each pair together in a nested subquery. With multiple tables, this query becomes very sluggish and unwieldy. How can I do this in a more parsimonious manner?

My current solution:

```
SELECT t1.userid
,t1.total_transactions
,t1.days_transact
,t2.total_vouchers
,t2.days_redeemed
FROM ( 
    SELECT u.userid 
    ,SUM(s.transactions) AS total_transactions
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.dated) AS days_transact
    FROM ( 
            SELECT userid 
            ,created 
            FROM schema.user_info
            ) u 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT userid 
            ,transactions
            ,dated 
            FROM schema.transactions
            ) s 
            ON u.userid = s.userid 
            AND s.dated BETWEEN u.created AND DATE_ADD(u.created, 61)
        GROUP BY u.userid
        ) t1 
        LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT u.userid 
          ,SUM(v.vouchers) AS total_vouchers
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.dated) AS days_redeemed
        FROM ( 
            SELECT userid 
            ,created 
            FROM schema.user_info
            ) u 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT userid 
            ,vouchers
            ,dated 
            FROM schema.vouchers
            ) v 
            ON u.userid = v.userid 
            AND v.dated BETWEEN u.created AND DATE_ADD(u.created, 61)
        GROUP BY u.userid
        ) t2
        ON t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Comment: "With multiple tables, this query becomes very sluggish and unwieldy" - slow queries are more indicative of missing indexes than query-complexity. Please post your execution-plan or `EXPLAIN` results.

Comment: You can make your query more readable (and less repetitive) if you use a CTE instead of inner queries.